# SSIS - How do I loop using results from an SQL task

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I'm trying to load a large amount of data from an SQL Server db to an Azure db
The load happens over a VPN that times out. So I'd like to load in smaller batches that I can restart at certain point when the load fails.

How can I use the following SQL to load data 1 month at a time using SSIS

```
declare @StartDate      date
declare @EndDate        date
declare @OverallEndDate date


--  Set the start date and overall end date
--  Set the end date to 1 month after the start date
set @OverallEndDate = '2021-03-31'
set @StartDate = '2019-01-01'
set @EndDate = dateadd( mm,1 ,@startDate)

--  Loop while the start date is less than the overall end date
while(@OverallEndDate > @StartDate)
begin
  Select count(*) from [lab03].[SFSHistUser]
    where CreatedDate >= @StartDate
    and   CreatedDate < @EndDate

--     Increment the month
  set @StartDate = @EndDate
  set @EndDate = dateadd( mm,1 ,@startDate)

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some kind of date table? The process should look something like this: you execute a query like `SELECT DISTINCT FirstOfMonth FROM MyTable` in a SQL task and as resultset you hae to set an object variable like `oListOfMonth`. Then you add a `For Each Loop Container` and define its Collection as `Foreach-ADO-Enumerator`. The ADO object source variable is the above mentioned object variable. Furthermore you have to define a variable where the loop can store it's current value which is maintained under `Variable Mappings`. Here you provide your variable name as `Variable` and 0 as `Index`.  Within the loop you can then perform all kind of tasks by referencing this variable.

Comment: Is the SQL task placed within the loop container or is the destination table placed within the loop container? 

Thanks again

Comment: The SQL task to load the list of dates / days / ... is placed outside the loop - afterall, you need it's result for the loop, so it has to be executed before you can loop through it. The Dataflow / Insert / ... is placed inside the loop. The variable of the loop (where each current value is contained) will then be the start of your filter, such as `...WHERE Date >= @variable AND Date < DATEADD(mm, 1, @variable)`.